# Is it possible to copy an extension from one site to another

Tags: magento-1.9

I have two sites and have an extension pre installed in one of the themes and want to know if I can copy it to the other theme? Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, if the extension doesn't have domains limit. But you need to find all the extension files:

1. /app/etc/Some_Extension.xml
2. /app/code/[community|local]/Some/Extension/

Possible, the files can be also found in:

- /app/design/adminhtml/
- /app/design/frontend/
- /js/
- /lib/
- /skin/adminhtml/
- /skin/frontend/