# Copying extensions from one site to another

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I'm new to `Magento` and currently need to stick with `Magento 1.9`, because of "reasons".

I have one site that I'm managing that's up and running well with a ton of extensions, that various people from years ago in my company purchased. I would like most if not all of those same extensions on brand new clients site.

I read [Is it possible to copy an extension from one site to another](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82230/is-it-possible-to-copy-an-extension-from-one-site-to-another) but It wasn't enough to get the job done.

I can see all of the extensions now, but it is still unclear how I should effectively copy all of those extensions and load them on my new site.

Hunting each of these extensions down is not working out, some of the credentials from their sources have even been lost. Can someone with experience doing this help me get my new site up and running with the same extensions from my other site...?

Comment: The answer you linked to covers the files on the filesystem that would need to be brought over. However, to get them working as they are in the current site, you will also need to consider any related configurations in the `core_config_data` table (including extension licenses that you may be violating - just sayin'). Then there are any customizations, including integrations with the frontend templates/css that may contribute to how the extension currently work. If you want close to everything, you could literally copy everything (filesystem & db) and then delete/update as needed.

Comment: First, you need to take a backup(Database/File structure) of your live site which is working smoothly. After complete this process, you need to set up again.
If anyone extension data has gone so you need to take only an appropriate extension database table and restore it in your live site. If you have any query reagarding any thing let me know in skyp tusharlathiya1996

Comment: Thank you, we'll give it a shot!